# How to disable the context menu within Ti.UI.iOS.createDocumentViewer within appcelerator titanium project?

Tags: titanium, titanium-sdk

I'm using [Ti.UI.IOS.DocumentViewer](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.iOS.DocumentViewer) within an application for displaying word, excel, pdf etc.. When opening a document the viewer presents a context menu with actions to share, print, etc. the document.

Does anyone know how to disable the context menu which occurs within the viewer on the right nav button place?